# Generate JIRA ticket using Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, jira, jira-rest-api

I am a project admin of JIRA not global admin. My company is changing from SP to JIRA.

Basically if a user adds an item in list of Sharepoint, I want it to be generated as ticket in JIRA.

I understand JIRA Isuue Collector needs global admin, but as project admin how to do this?

I am admin of Sharepoint Site as well.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should post this question using JIRA tag. From sharepoint you can write an event receiver which on item added/update calls any JIRA api (if available) to update info in JIRA.